# Problem with guard-test compiling asset cache files

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, testunit, guard

Running tests using guard-test compiles asset cache files. This does not occur when I run tests normally using rake. My test.rb environment specifies config.action_controller.perform_caching = false. I am overriding host and using sub-domains if that makes any difference.

Functional:
    @request.host = "sub.domain.devnet"

Integration:
    host! "sub.domain.devnet"
    Capybara.default_host = "sub.domain.devnet"

All tests are green.

Answer (score 0):

do you have `ENV["RAILS_ENV"] ||= 'test'` in your `test/test_helper.rb` file?

Maybe the normal rake task automatically set it?

Comment: Yes I have ENV["RAILS_ENV"] = "test". Can't seem any indication of a different environment being used though. My other environments would send out emails. And there is only logs for development and test in my log folder. My dev env also has disabled asset cache files.

Comment: I added Rails.env to the asset cache filename and it is run under test environment.

Comment: Can you run Guard with the --debug (or -d) flag to see which files guard-test run?

Comment: I have another project and I also tried specifying :cache => "filename" for assets and they are not generated in the test env. That project does not test different subdomains though, so maybe that is an issue. Running guard in debug mode doesn't print out anything else than running without debug.